# ui-router resolve with dynamic parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

This is probably simple but I can't find anything in the docs and googling didn't help. I'm trying to define a state in `$stateProvider` where the URL I need to hit on the server to pull the needed data depends on a state URL parameter. In short, something like:

```
 .state('recipes.category', {
    url: '/:cat',
    templateUrl: '/partials/recipes.category.html',
    controller: 'RecipesCategoryCtrl',
    resolve: {
      category: function($http) {
        return $http.get('/recipes/' + cat)
          .then(function(data) { return data.data; });
      }
    }
  })
```

The above doesn't work. I tried injecting `$routeParams` to get the needed `cat` parameter, with no luck. What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You were close with `$routeParams`. If you use ui-router use `$stateParams` instead. 
This code works for me:

```
.state('recipes.category', {
    url: '/:cat',
    templateUrl: '/partials/recipes.category.html',
    controller: 'RecipesCategoryCtrl',
    resolve: {
         category: ['$http','$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
             return $http.get('/recipes/' + $stateParams.cat)
                    .then(function(data) { return data.data; });
         }]
     }
})
```

Comment: And how to get `category` in controller RecipesCategoryCtrl ?

Comment: just inject it: `RecipesCategoryCtrl = function($scope, category) { $scope.cat = category }`

Comment: $stateParams will only return parameters that are given in the url (as {param} or :param).  I do not want my target state to have a URL.  Furthermore, the parameter is an object.  To pass it this way I would have to convert it to JSON first then parse it back.  Too slow and messy.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are using ui-router 1.0 `$stateParams` [is deprecated](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#stateparams-deprecation), you should use [`$transition$`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html) object instead:

```js
.state('recipes.category', {
    url: '/:cat',
    templateUrl: '/partials/recipes.category.html',
    controller: 'RecipesCategoryCtrl',
    resolve: {
         category: ['$http','$transition$', function($http, $transition$) {
             return $http.get('/recipes/' + $transition$.params().cat)
                    .then(function(data) { return data.data; });
         }]
     }
})
```