# Angular - routing resolve service issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angular application.

In the current build - there is a controller that gets invoked when a user presses a button - it opens up a modal window and populates the contents as such.

I am trying to remove the modal and reconfigure the application, so that it goes to a new page

The first page is a list of people `/people`
When you click a person, it will go to a page like `/people/view/34323`

I am trying to configure the app stateprovider stack like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('people-view', {
    url: "/people/view/:id",
    templateUrl: "partials/people/people-view.html",
    controller: personDialogController,
    resolve: {
        politicservice:function(personservice){
            personservice.getPolitics(id).then = persondata.data;
        }
        biography:function(personservice){
            personservice.getBio(id).then = persondata.data;
        }
        dialogueId:function(personservice){
            //id
        }
    }
})
```

This will create the basic page...but the services that used to work for this controller now don't.

It's as if the id is not being passed into the resolve functions and it's as if the `persondata` `then`, the promise is not calling back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$stateParams` to the resolve function:

```
$stateProvider
.state('people-view', {
    url: "/people/view/:id",
    templateUrl: "partials/people/people-view.html",
    controller: personDialogController,
    resolve: 
        politicservice:function(personservice, $stateParams){
            return personservice.getPolitics($stateParams.id);
        }
        biography:function(personservice, $stateParams){
            return personservice.getBio($stateParams.id);
        }
        dialogueId:function(personservice, $stateParams){
            //$stateParams.id
        }
})
```

`$stateParams` will contain an object of all the parameters as defined in the url string. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012579/ui-router-resolve-with-dynamic-parameters) question for more information.

Comment: Its also written in coffee script. -- still I did try and hard code the id into the service function - and it still didn't take.. maybe it wasn't the correct expected case?

Comment: What happens if you just `console.log($state)` from within one of the resolve functions?

Comment: _ I would have to check it out tomorrow. It was a task I was stuck on at the end of play today.

Comment: When I do a console log -- I see the $state -- but when I try to drill down it comes up null --  console.log('state.params', $state.params);
                  console.log('state', $state);
                  console.log('state.params.id', $state.params.id);
                  console.log('state.current', $state.current);

Comment: And you're passing `$state` in to the function, correct?

Comment: And are you using `ng-route` or `ui-router`?

Comment: $stateParams - returned the id

Comment: personservice.getPolitics($stateParams.id).then = persondata.data;  -- doesn't seem to work -- the id is going in, I can see the function at that level - but its not coming back with anything - persondata appears empty

Comment: PersonService.getPolitics($stateParams.id).then (personRequest) -> personRequest.data
            console.log('personRequest', personRequest)

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to return the promise.

Comment: but what about the -- then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118405/discussion-between-frankerz-and-the-old-county).