# Angularjs: Retrieve data from state params and use it in resolve

Tags: angularjs

got some question for you guys.
How can i retrieve data passed as parameter and use it as object/string in my resolve so i can pass it to my controller.

here is my code(not working)

```
var thisState  =   {
                   name: 'category',
                   url: '/category/:category',
                   templateUrl: 'resources/templates/views/category.html',
                   resolve: {
                      category: function(params) {
                        return params.category;             
                      }
                   },
                   controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
                }

 $stateProvider
 .state(thisState);
```

this is how i pass param

```
ui-sref="category({category:'food'})
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this discussion solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012579/ui-router-resolve-with-dynamic-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) with ui-router

```
var thisState  =   {
                   name: 'category'
                   url: '/category/:category',
                   templateUrl: 'resources/templates/views/category.html',
                   resolve: {
                      category: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                          return $stateParams.category;
                      }]
                   },
                   controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
                }

 $stateProvider
 .state(thisState);
```

Comment: @arnoldemzi Thanks and You are welcome, don't forget to accept it as answer to close your question. Have a good day :)